# Problem with Perl installation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shared-library, perl

I am an inexperienced user. I have two different bioinformatics applications using different Perl libraries. I get the following error when trying to execute one of them:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /home/karen/.t_coffee/perl/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Encode/Encode.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
```

I understand that the app is being directed to the wrong Perl library, but I don't know how to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that 20.04 LTS is relatively fresh and uses [perl 5.30](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/perl). Which Perl version do you have inside `~/.t_coffee/perl`?  Will moving `~/.t_coffee/perl` to the temporary new place fix the issue?

Comment: The version in ~/.t_coffee/perl/lib is perl5.  Yes, that works! Can I remove it permanently? Thanks very much.

Comment: I think - yes, you can remove them. But it is your files, so you will decide :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue you have to move `~/.t_coffee/perl` to the temporary new place.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is more like "it's complicated", since it is likely that renaming the `~/.t_coffee/perl` folder will cause the t-cofee application to stop working, though it may allow the other application to continue.

the error message seems to indicate you are using [T-Coffee](http://www.tcoffee.org/Projects/tcoffee/), but you don't mention the other bioinformatics application, which may be useful in helping you find a solution.

Looking at the source distribution for t_coffee it looks like the manipulate many environment variables, including the PATH, and their installation instructions also mention modifying your .bashrc.